# Prove the given relation between $f(x)$et

Tags: combinatorics, functions, contest-math

Let $$f(n)=\sum_{r=0}^{\big\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}\big\rfloor}} {{n-r} \choose r}$$

Prove,

$$f(x-2)+f(x-1)=f(x)$$

I don't know where to start. An someone help me solving this?

Comment: Is $x=n$?  In any case, induction seems natural.

Comment: Induction is unnecessary; write down the sums and try to simplify. If you don't know where to start, look at some small cases and see what happens (don't simplify the whole thing to a number, that won't be educational; look at what the terms of the sums do and how they can be combined).

Comment: @MishaLavrov for example $x=20$, $f(x)$ will have $11$ terms and $f(x-2),f(x-1)$ will have 10 terms each so terms willn't match. And also the first and last terms of each can be simplified in terms of $f(x)$ but not the same for middle ones.

Comment: @lulu can you prove by induction?

Comment: You can, but I agree with @MishaLavrov that it isn't necessary. In any case, working it out carefully for small $n$ is the right place to start.

Comment: @Krish So look at those terms! How can $$f(18)=1+17+120+455+1001+1287+924+330+45+1$$ and $$f(19)=1+18+136+560+1365+2002+1716+792+165+10$$ be manipulated to get $$f(20)=1+19+153+680+1820+3003+3003+1716+495+55+1$$ without having to simplify all three sums any further?